# How to fetch attachments within ItemAttachment using EWS Java

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I have a mail attachment where I want to extract the attachments from IteAttachment which is part of an attachment to an email.I could able to extract the files file attachments.

Point to be remember here is ItemAttachment can still have one more ItemAttachment inside, so I want the code that will work recursively to fetch all the attachments until it doesn't find the any more ItemAttachment.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation and Code sample taken from official Microsoft Documentation

[Get attachments from an email by using the EWS Managed API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-get-attachments-by-using-ews-in-exchange#get-attachments-from-an-email-by-using-the-ews-managed-api)

> The following code example shows how to get an EmailMessage object by
>   using the Bind method, then iterate through the attachment collection
>   and call the FileAttachment.Load or ItemAttachment.Load method on each
>   attachment as appropriate. Each file attachment is saved to the
>   C:\temp\ folder, and each item attachment is loaded into memory. For
>   information about how to save an item attachment, see Save an attached
>   email by using the EWS Managed API.
>
> This example assumes that service is a valid ExchangeService object,
>   that itemId is the ItemId of the message from which attachments will
>   be retrieved, and that the user has been authenticated to an Exchange
>   server.

```
public static void GetAttachmentsFromEmail(ExchangeService service, ItemId itemId)
{
    // Bind to an existing message item and retrieve the attachments collection.
    // This method results in an GetItem call to EWS.
    EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, itemId, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Attachments));
    // Iterate through the attachments collection and load each attachment.
    foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
    {
        if (attachment is FileAttachment)
        {
            FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
            // Load the attachment into a file.
            // This call results in a GetAttachment call to EWS.
            fileAttachment.Load("C:\\temp\\" + fileAttachment.Name);

            Console.WriteLine("File attachment name: " + fileAttachment.Name);
        }
        else // Attachment is an item attachment.
        {
            ItemAttachment itemAttachment = attachment as ItemAttachment;
            // Load attachment into memory and write out the subject.
            // This does not save the file like it does with a file attachment.
            // This call results in a GetAttachment call to EWS.
            itemAttachment.Load();
            Console.WriteLine("Item attachment name: " + itemAttachment.Name);
        }
    }
}
```